FastReport CompilerException: How to Properly Register and Use Data Source OperationSupplies?
I'm currently working on a FastReport project in a .NET application and am encountering a CompilerException when trying to use the OperationSupplies data source. Here’s the context of my issue:
Problem Description
I have defined two data sources in my FastReport report: Operations and OperationSupplies. While the Operations data source is working correctly, I’m facing issues with the OperationSupplies data source. Specifically, I get the following compilation errors:
FastReport.Utils.CompilerException: (Cell191): Error CS0103: The name 'OperationSupplies' does not exist in the current context
(Cell192): Error CS0103: The name 'OperationSupplies' does not exist in the current context
(Cell193): Error CS0103: The name 'OperationSupplies' does not exist in the current context
(Cell194): Error CS0103: The name 'OperationSupplies' does not exist in the current context
my data source is
<BusinessObjectDataSource Name="Operations" ReferenceName="Operations" DataType="null" Enabled="true">
  <Column Name="Id" DataType="System.Int32"/>
  <Column Name="AdmissionPatientId" DataType="System.Int32"/>
  <Column Name="AdmissionPatientName" DataType="System.String"/>
  <Column Name="OperationName" DataType="System.String"/>
  <Column Name="OperationCode" DataType="System.String"/>
  <BusinessObjectDataSource Name="OperationSupplies" ReferenceName="OperationSupplies" DataType="null" Enabled="true">
    <Column Name="Medicine" DataType="System.String"/>
    <Column Name="Description" DataType="System.String"/>
    <Column Name="Route" DataType="System.String"/>
    <Column Name="Quantity" DataType="System.Int32"/>
  </BusinessObjectDataSource>
</BusinessObjectDataSource>

and my code is
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> PrintOperationsListReport(int type, DateTime? DateFrom, DateTime? DateTo, int? DoctorId)
{
    var DoctorName = "";
    var model = await _operationsRepository.GetOperationsForReport(DateFrom, DateTo, DoctorId);

    if (DoctorId != 0)
    {
        var doctorRequestModel = new GetDoctorOneQuery()
        {
            DoctorId = DoctorId ?? 0,
        };
        var doctorInfo = await mediator.Send(doctorRequestModel);
        DoctorName = doctorInfo.FirstName + " " + doctorInfo.LastName;
    }
    WebReport web = new WebReport();
    string path = "";
    string reportName = type == 0 ? "OperationsListReport" : "OperationsListReportWithConsumables";
    path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"\\wwwroot\\reports\\{reportName}.frx";

    web.Report.Load(path);

    PictureObject picture = web.Report.FindObject("Picture1") as PictureObject;
    var company = await mediator.Send(new GetCompanyInfoQuery());
    string url = company == null ? "" : company.UrlReport;
    picture.ImageLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot\\Upload\\" + url;

    var total = model.Sum(a => a.Total);
    var operationsTotalPrice = model.Sum(a => a.OperationPrice);

    web.Report.SetParameterValue("FromDate", DateFrom.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    web.Report.SetParameterValue("ToDate", DateTo.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    web.Report.SetParameterValue("AllTotal", total);
    web.Report.SetParameterValue("OperationsPriceTotal", operationsTotalPrice);
    web.Report.SetParameterValue("NetProfit", operationsTotalPrice - total);
    web.Report.SetParameterValue("DoctorName", DoctorName);


    web.Report.RegisterData(model, "Operations");
    // Register nested data source
    foreach (var operation in model)
    {
        web.Report.RegisterData(operation.OperationSupplies, "Operations.OperationSupplies");
    }

    //var check = web.Report.GetDataSource("Operations");
    //var check2 = web.Report.GetDataSource("Operations.OperationSupplies");
    web.Report.Prepare();

    string export = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"\\wwwroot\\export\\{reportName}.pdf";
    web.Report.Export(new PDFSimpleExport(), export);


    return Ok(true);
}


Did you bind the data source correctly in the designer?
